# Locally Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have been reading a review of paper "Completely factorizable group" by Baeva on mathscinet.

The reviewer has used term "locally abelian group". I search a lot about this and I can't find the definition of "locally abelian group".

Please advise me

Comment: In general, given a class $C$ of groups, we say that a group $G$ is locally $C$, if every finite subset of $G$ generates a subgroup belonging to this class (some others use a more general definition), so I think locally abelian means that every finitely generated subgroup is abelian.

Comment: @YassineGuerboussa It's natural that I think as you thought but I am not sure. there is not ref which confirms it.

Comment: So I am not sure, but I think if the notion is not specified in the paper, it follows the general sens.

Comment: I'd say it is what Yassine says but in this case it makes no sense: a group is locally abelian iff it is abelian, since if the group wasn't abelian there'd be $\;x,y\in G\;$ with $\;xy\neq yx\;$ , but then $\;\langle x,y\rangle\;$ isn't abelian, contradiction. This is weird...

Comment: @DonAntonio : you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general definition is as follows. Let $\cal C$ be a class of groups and $G$ a
group. Then $G$ is called a locally $\cal C$-group, provided that for each finite
subset
$X$ of $G$ there exists $Y\leq G$ with $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\in {\cal C}$.

1.) A locally abelian group is obviously abelian.

2.) A bit less obviously, a locally simple group is simple.

Comment: with your definition every abelian group is locally abelian group. So abelian group equivalents to locally abelian group!!

Comment: For abelian yes, in general a locally $\mathcal{C}$-group need not be the same as a $\mathcal{C}$-group. The definition is standard (and not mine).